# Process Forks Shell, Then Entire Program Is Stopped?

Tags: c, linux, bash, fork, exec

I have a program copied from the man page for pipe(2), modified so that the child forks off a shell, and the parent reads from stdin, sending the commands to the child shell to be executed.  This works for the first command, but after that command is run, I get a message that the program has stopped and I'm returned to the top-level shell.

Why does that happen, and how can I stop it?

signal(7) says:

```
   SIGTTIN      P1990      Stop    Terminal input for background process
```

But it's not supposed to be a background process, so why is it stopping?

What follows is a terminal session with the full source code, the result of gcc -Wall, and trying to run the program.  As you can see, I give the command "date", then I'm sent back
to the invoking shell, then the child shell executes "date" and the output appears, then an "exit" appears.  "fg" gets me back into the pipe_shell program, "uptime" is sent to the shell and run, then I can do an "echo", and I get sent back to the top-level shell and "exit" appears again.

```
sh-5.0$ cat pipe_shell.c
/* pipe_shell.c - learn about pipes
 *
 * Modified from the man page for pipe(2).
 */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int   pipefd[2];
    pid_t cpid;

    if (argc != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cpid = fork();
    if (cpid == -1) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (cpid == 0) { // Child reads from pipe

        close(pipefd[1]);              // Close unused write end of pipe
        close(STDIN_FILENO);           // shut off standard input
        dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO); // pipe output is standard input
        close(pipefd[0]);              // close pipe output

        execl("/bin/bash", "bash",
              "--norc",
              "-i",
              (char *) 0);

        perror("exec");

    } else { // Parent writes to pipe
        close(pipefd[0]);    // Close unused read end

        char line[256];      // we take input from keyboard
        while ( fgets(line, 255, stdin) != NULL ) {
            write(pipefd[1], line, strlen(line));
        }

        close(pipefd[1]);    // Reader will see EOF
        wait(NULL);          // Wait for child
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
}
sh-5.0$ gcc -Wall pipe_shell.c -o pipe_shell
sh-5.0$ ./pipe_shell
bash-5.0$ date

date
[1]+  Stopped(SIGTTIN)        ./pipe_shell
sh-5.0$ Wed 10 Jun 2020 12:16:28 PM EDT
bash-5.0$ exit
There are stopped jobs.
sh-5.0$ fg
./pipe_shell
uptime
uptime
 12:16:52 up 154 days, 23:32,  5 users,  load average: 0.04, 0.05, 0.07
bash-5.0$ echo "foo"

[1]+  Stopped(SIGTTIN)        ./pipe_shell
echo "foo"
sh-5.0$ foo
bash-5.0$ exit
exit
```

Comment: Did you read [*advanced linux programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) then [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and [termios(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) and [signal(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and [signal-safety(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html) and [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) ? Did you study the source code of e.g. [zsh](http://zsh.org/) ?

Comment: No, I inherited 12,000 lines of code that don't quite work and was told to fix it.  I tracked the problem down to a hunk that does something like this, and then reproduced it starting from the man page.  I'll be perfectly happy to read all that stuff, if you can narrow down where I should start.

Comment: 12000 lines is small. You can use [GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/), [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [ltrace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ltrace.1.html) and the [Clang analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) to understand them. Perhaps also write your own [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html). Budget several months of work. Look also into the source code of [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sash_shell)

Comment: But StackOverflow is not a do-my-work website. Provide some [mre] in your next questions.

Comment: That is a minimal reproducible example, that's why I included it.

Comment: Does `set +m` in the subshell improve things?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This looks like a reasonable question with a good MCVE to me.

Comment: Interestingly, if the first command in the subshell is "set +m", it gets stopped as before, but when foregrounded it doesn't get stopped again.  Somehow it seems that the "set +m" doesn't take effect?  I modified the exec to include an "--rcfile" with "set +m" in it, but that doesn't seem to make any difference at all.  One solution might be to compile a bash without job control and just use that one.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your program without the `-i` option for `bash`, though you won't see a prompt.

Oversimplified, SIGTTIN issues relate to `read()`, a control tty, and process groups.  For details, a decent starting point is google.com with search terms: `linux SIGTTIN`; there are some articles that delve into read / tty / pgrp.

To run an interactive shell similar to your small program and possibly resolve an issue with your large program, you could make use of master/slave pseudo devices.  There's a  related lib service `forkpty()`.  Also, there's a UNIX/linux utility named `script` that records an interactive shell session to a regular file; the source code for `script` is a good example of reader + writer processes, master/slave pseudo devices, and an interactive shell.

Comment: I know about `script`, but somehow didn't think of that as an example.  Thanks for the suggestion; I'm off to look at more source code.